# Как обновлять другое окно в TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

По задумке это обычный блэкджэк, но мне нужно обновлять d, чтобы добавлялись карты при нажатии кнопки.
Я пробовал различные способы  описанные в интернете, но ничего не помогло мне.

```py
def creategame():
    game = Toplevel(root)
    game.title('Игра')
    game.geometry("1880x1260+0+0")
    Button(game , command= button_give,text= "Взять карту").pack()
    h = Label(game , text=robot_current ,font= "Times 80",width= 100 ).pack()
    d = Label(game,text=global_current , font= "Times 80",height = 900,width= 50)
    d.pack()
```

Функция button give:

```py
def button_give():
    current = a.pop()
    #count += current
    '''if count > 21:
        count == 0'''
    if current == 11 :
            current = random.choice(piki)
    if current == 2:
                    current = random.choice(dva)
    if current == 3:
                    current = random.choice(three)
    if current == 4:
                    current = random.choice(four)
    if current == 5:
                    current = random.choice(five)
    if current == 6:
                    current = random.choice(six)
    if current == 7:
                    current = random.choice(seven)
    if current == 8:
                    current = random.choice(eigth)
    if current == 9:
                    current = random.choice(nine)
    if current == 10:
                    current = random.choice(ten)  
    global_current.append(current)
```

Comment: если убрать def creategame() а просто так разместить все эти кнопочки, то будет норм работать d.config(text = global_current) внутри button_give()

Comment: Огромное спасибо!